# Is Wi-Fi power saving smart enough to only actually take effect when on battery (no power plug)?

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, networkmanager, power-management

Referring to `NetworkManager` commit [6bb0cffba32ec925743c4d491b75474d4e855198](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/commit/?id=6bb0cffba32ec925743c4d491b75474d4e855198) implementing [dynamic power save](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/dynamic-power-save) (DPS) as advertised in "[Manage Wi-Fi latency and dynamic power-savings on Linux](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/linux-wifi-dpm-latency.html)", I am now wondering whether permanently enabling Wi-Fi power saving with either `iw`:

```
$ iw ${if} set power_save on
```

or `NetworkManager`:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave=3
```

would degrade Wi-Fi performance when still remaining on power plug (not running on battery)?  Intuitively, the drivers should be smart enough to deal with this and only actually apply power-saving policy when there is no power plug.  Any expertise or verifications on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manually set:

```
$ iw ${if} set power_save on
```

and no other power management tool is working, then power saving will be on, whether you plug the computer or not.

If you have a power manager tool, its task will be to set/unset power saving accordingly.

That could be as simple as battery/mains a bit more complex (with battery thresholds or UPS status) or even considering how and to which network you are connected (you might need more energy to be listened, depending on the conditions).

So no, the drivers are not *smart* to know about all those possible conditions and triggers, they rely on an external agent (you, or something like [TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/)) to decide for them and communicate the decision to turn power saving on/off.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for TLP pointer.  All the best!